# C - Login using file handling and linked list

Tags: c, function, data-structures, linked-list, file-handling

I am creating an account using Create New Account option, & then writing the created username pwd to the file, but when I rerun the code & try to login using the same id, it fails. Using string compare, but it seems string is not being read.

```
struct user{
    char username[10];
    char password[10];
    struct user *next;
}*sUser,*pUser; 

userlogin(void){
FILE *fp;
char uName[10], pwd[10];int i;char c;
sUser=pUser=(struct user *)malloc(sizeof(struct user));

printf("1. Login Through An Existing Account\n2. Create New account\n");
        scanf("%d",& i);
        system("cls");
        switch(i){
            case 1:
                fp=fopen("user.dat", "w");
                printf("Username: ");
                scanf("%s",&uName);
                printf("Password: ");
                scanf("%s",&pwd);
                fread (pUser, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);
                while(pUser!=NULL){
                    if(pUser->username==uName){
                        if(pUser->password==pwd){
                            accessUser();
                        }
                    }
                    pUser=pUser->next;
                }
                break;

            case 2: 
                do
                {
                    fp=fopen("user.dat", "r");
                    printf("Choose A Username: ");
                    scanf("%s",&pUser->username);
                    printf("Choose A Password: ");
                    scanf("%s",&pUser->password);
                    printf("Add another account? (Y/N): ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%c",&c);
                    if(c=='Y'||c=='y'){
                        pUser->next=(struct user*)malloc(sizeof(struct user));
                    }
                }while(c=='Y'||c=='y');
                pUser->next==NULL;
                fwrite (sUser, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);
                break;
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
```

**EDIT:**
The value of pUser->username is not what it should be

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong. 
Does this have anything to do with the fact that I'm rerunning the code so maybe the pointers are reallocated and not pointing to where they should?
In that case, how do I store the pointers so that they aren't changed from the first run.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and going through step by step to see the actual values?

Comment: @GrawCube Yeah I tried going through trace but it just skips the if condition by itself, the pUser->username value is not what it should be

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not how this site works. Please try to cook your problem down to a minimal example. There are great chances that your problem has nothing to do with "login", functions or any other of the tags.

Comment: As a side note, it's busywork like this that I think current programming teachers should all be fired. "Login using file handling and linked lists" wtf is that? If you want to make a login system, use proper login practices: hashed and salted passwords, encrypted files (or hidden behind server side walls), proper queries etc. There's plenty of good uses for flat files, and this is not one of them.

Comment: I'm a freshman and this is my first major project or any programming experience. Yeah, you could be right about the stuff you said I should use but I am just new to any sort of programming so I think that these basics would lead me to whatever you're talking about. Also, I'm doing all this by myself, without the help of any teacher.

Comment: I'm using the same code to save to the structures, first I'm adding a username and password using the 2nd case , then I re run the code and try to match using 1st one @user3121023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't strictly a linked list as the structures are not read into memory.
For this, the *next pointer isn't used. Each structure is read from the file and the strcmp comparisons check for equality.
For adding structures the file is opened using "a+" to append to the file.
If either attempt at opening the file fails, it tries again using "w+" and if that fails, the program exits.
Unsure what `accessUser()` was supposed to do, so it is commented out.
A function could be added to read all the structures into memory and link them using the *next pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void userlogin(void);

struct user{
    char username[10];
    char password[10];
}*pUser;

int main()
{
    userlogin ( );

    return 0;
}

void userlogin(void){
    FILE *fp;
    char uName[10], pwd[10];int i;char c;

    pUser=(struct user *)malloc(sizeof(struct user));

    printf("1. Login Through An Existing Account\n2. Create New account\n");
    scanf("%d",& i);
    //system("cls");
    switch(i){
        case 1:
            if ( ( fp=fopen("user.dat", "r+")) == NULL) {
                if ( ( fp=fopen("user.dat", "w+")) == NULL) {
                    printf ("Could not open file\n");
                    exit ( 1);
                }
            }
            printf("Username: ");
            scanf("%9s",uName);
            printf("Password: ");
            scanf("%9s",pwd);
            while ( fread (pUser, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp) == 1) {
                if( strcmp ( pUser->username, uName) == 0) {
                    printf ("Match username\n");
                    if( strcmp ( pUser->password, pwd) == 0) {
                        printf ("Match password\n");
                        //accessUser();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            do
            {
                if ( ( fp=fopen("user.dat", "a+")) == NULL) {
                    if ( ( fp=fopen("user.dat", "w+")) == NULL) {
                        printf ("Could not open file\n");
                        exit ( 1);
                    }
                }
                printf("Choose A Username: ");
                scanf("%9s",pUser->username);
                printf("Choose A Password: ");
                scanf("%9s",pUser->password);
                fwrite (pUser, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);
                printf("Add another account? (Y/N): ");
                scanf(" %c",&c);//skip leading whitespace
            }while(c=='Y'||c=='y');
            break;
    }
    free ( pUser);//free allocated memory
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to clear the buffer in CodeBlocks? Like , in new account creation, if we add a new password which is more than 9 characters, the next confirmation to add another account gets executed by itself, I mean it doesn't take Y or N it just skips out...
I've used fflush("stdin") but it crashes my codeblocks, don't know why

Answer (score 1):

String comparison doesn't work with the `==` in C. Use `strcmp` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
printf("Username: ");
scanf("%s",&uName);
printf("Password: ");
scanf("%s",&pwd);
```

with:

```
printf("Username: ");
scanf("%s", uName);
printf("Password: ");
scanf("%s", pwd);
```

Same with:

```
printf("Choose A Username: ");
scanf("%s",&pUser->username);
printf("Choose A Password: ");
scanf("%s",&pUser->password);
```

(remove the ampersand `&`). This is because for array of char, the variable name is treated as pointer.

Also string comparison is not correct. Replace:

```
if(pUser->username==uName)
if(pUser->password==pwd)
```

with:

```
if ( strcmp(pUser->username, uName) == 0 )
if ( strcmp(pUser->password, pwd) == 0 )
```

Comment: Still not working ! Though now somehow the username is matching to the string but the password is not

Comment: @Shubhendu, this just shows that you are trying to do (learn) too many things at a time. Start slowly with a trivial program that compiles and works, and then add one feature at a time.

Comment: @JensGustedt Everything's working fine upto this step, username is matching but password isn't

Answer (score 1):

wrong:
in case 1 you are opening file in write mode but you read data in that case.similarly ssecond case file a opening in read mode but you write data in that case

correction:
open file in 1 case in read mode and in second case in write mode.